# Can't find Python executable , enmap-sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I tried to install `enmap-sqlite` module , but it gave me this error (I already set the PYTHON variable with the complete path)

```js
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Zimobot\node_modules\integer>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\desktop\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\desktop\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\yassi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\desktop\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\desktop\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\desktop\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:170:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\desktop\\node.exe" "C:\\desktop\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\Zimobot\node_modules\integer
gyp ERR! node -v v9.7.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.0 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.0 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.0 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.0 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.5.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.3.0 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN quote@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN quote@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! integer@1.0.3 install: `node tools/install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the integer@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-03T22_07_34_566Z-debug.log
```

Can someones help me ?

Comment: Can you confirm that `python.exe` exists in `C:\Users\yassi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32` directory?

Comment: Yeah, i checked it.

Comment: And what happens when you type python in command prompt?

Comment: "python" didn't worked but "py".

Comment: So, you have variable `py` set, not `python`, as far as I can say.

Comment: So i need to set PYTHON variable to py ?

Comment: You can set an environment path variable. So that python is detected from anywhere in cmd. Refer to this answer: `https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa`